# "Christian Mingle, which is confusing, because if your name's Christian, why meet someone else named Christian?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have a quick question, if the people referring to Christian Mingle, they said:

> Christian Mingle, which is confusing, because if your name's Christian, why meet someone else named Christian?

Could you help me to clarify "if your name's Christian" referring to people who follow Christian?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to where you saw that sentence? On its own, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Hi, I don't have it online, just hear it. They're talking about dating app and Christian Mingle is an app that caters to Christian singles.

Comment: I think it's a little joke. Some people  have Christian as a first name. The speaker is suggesting that the app is for people whose name is Christian to meet other people whose name is Christian.

Answer (score 1):

"Christian" is an adjective (meaning a follower of Jesus Christ).  It is also a rare first name in English-speaking countries.

> Christian Bale won an Academy award for *The Fighter*.

The app name "Christian Mingle" is intended to suggest "Followers of Christ can mingle with each other using this app".

These people are suggesting (perhaps as a joke) that it might be understood as "People with the name "Christian" can mingle with each other using this app".

Comment: Actually, the mutineer's name was Fletcher Christian, but I agree with all the rest.

Comment: True... How about Christian Bale

Comment: I don't know that I'd call it a rare first name, though it's not a common one. In the US, "Christian has reach[ed] the top 10 most popular boys['] name[s] 2 times, and has reached the top hundred names 38 times" ( https://www.everything-birthday.com/name/m/christian - a site with awful grammar, but the maths might be right, I suppose).